# Online monitoring / dashboard service for multiple metrics

Tags: backup, web-server, monitoring

I know there are services like Uptimerobot and Pingdom that monitor web service uptime.

I'd like to easily monitor web availability as well as backup status, eg if a backup ran/ completed properly. I'd like to avoid the backup script filling my inbox with emails and just have a single webpage to check every metric at a glance.

I'd like to know if there is an online service that can provide a dashboard view of several metrics like

- web availability/uptime
- backup status (did it run, size of backup vs source, etc)
- other webserver variables (load, disk, etc)

Is there such a thing?

I'm guess there would need to be a way to submit data to the service over an API and then a front-end traffic light system or other easy to use indicator to see status at a glance.

Thanks!

Comment: Product and service recommendations are off topic.

Comment: *"I'd like to avoid the backup script filling my inbox with emails"*  ==> https://opsreportcard.com/section/18

Answer (score 1):

Datadog monitors web availability, server performance, backup status. https://www.datadoghq.com/

Answer (score 1):

Many monitoring services support and provide agents to monitor all kinds of properties on your servers as well as custom checks for things/metrics  they don't support natively already.

1. Install the agent and you should get many useful metrics.

---

In addition even basic/trivial web site monitoring services allow you to define additional URL's to check.

Consider setting up a (password protected) monitoring area on your website where you can deploy trivial web services for such custom monitoring.

Then for example have your backup script log a date/time, success or failure and whatever else you deem important to a status file and create a trivial web service that parses that file, something along the lines of the pseudo code below:

```
if ( modification_time( backup_log_file ) > 36 hours) 
then 
    send http_response_header = 500
    send http_response_body   = "RED: the last successful backup is more than 36 hours old"
fi

if ( backup_log_file  CONTAINS_STRING "success" )
then 
    send http_response_header = 200
    send http_response_body   = "GREEN: the last backup was successful"
else
    send http_response_header = 500
    send http_response_body   = "RED: the last backup failed"    
fi
```